# My "flag" option is gone from Aperture — where did it go and how do I get it back?

Tags: software, apple-aperture

I have always used the "flag" option to tag my favorite pictures to go to later, but for some reason it's no longer there.  Did I accidentally press on something that took it away?? Anyone know what I did, and how to get it back?  Help!

Answer (score 5):

Question - when you say "it's no longer there", what are you looking for that you're not seeing?  If you select a picture and hit "/", you don't get a flag in the upper-right corner?  If that's the case, go to View > Metadata Display, and make sure that both Viewer and Browser have the "show metadata" option selected.  It looks to me like it might be really easy to hit "y" which turns that on & off in the viewer, and that might be your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I actually still have the problem of the flags and colors not showing beneath my photos in both the viewer and browser. Would you have any more suggestions?
Thank you,

Comment: Hi @Dawn - can you post a link to a screenshot of what you are seeing?  Shift-cmd-3 to grab entire screen(s), shift-cmd-4 to grab a portion of the screen.  It'll save to a png or pdf, usually to your desktop.  If you can show me what you're seeing, that might help.  Also, what version of Aperture are you using?  That will be available under the Aperture > About Aperture menu option.  For reference, I'm on 3.5.1 now.